# Run Nunit tests from published artifacts

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

The team city documentation (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/NUnit) shows how to specify the path(s) in which to search for assemblies to run unit test from.

My build step only builds a portion of my repository, and packages the output of this build in to several artifacts.  Ideally I would only like to run unit tests against the assemblies that are produced in one (or more) of these artifacts.  Is it possible to run unit tests on assemblies contained within artifacts that are produced by the previous build step?

I am aware that I could achieve my goal by simply refining the paths described in the first statement to only cover those directories included in the build - but I would prefer to find a way to run the tests contained within the artifacts if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Artifacts are really not that different from using file folders - personally I would use the option you described - an alternative would be breaking up your build steps into separate build configurations and use either a snapshot dependency or build trigger to chain them.

1) Create one ore multiple artifact dependencies from build B to build A and extract your assemblies into a folder, e.g. `a.zip!**=>destination`, [more detailed instructions are here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Artifact+Dependencies#ArtifactDependencies-ConfiguringArtifactDependenciesUsingWebUI).

2) Configure nUnit to run unit tests from the destination folder using a wildcard, e.g. `**\destination\*.dll`